# Cascading to avoid glitches? - VHDL

Tags: vhdl

[image: Glitch]

I am in the process of relearning VHDL. After encountering some issues, I went back to trivial stuff like an alarm clock. I guess I have a basic misconception and wrong approach after years of Java etc. instead of hardware stuff. Please point me in the right direction regarding my general questions below (always referring to trivial cases, I am using Xilinx ISE and Spartan3, but my questions are independent of actual hardware).

1. Counters produce glitches in the hardware (simulation) because of the bit toggling. That is to be expected. How to compensate for that in the design?
   E.g. part of the process would be:

   ```
   if rising_edge(clk_base) then
      if(set_time='1') 
           if (sec_enable= '1') then
               sec1 <= sec1+1;
               if(sec1 = 59) then
                   sec1<=0;
               end if;
           end if;   ....
   ```

   After the process, I write output_seconds <= sec1;  So apparently, with this non-sequential (?) statement outside the process, I always get the glitches directly at the output port. Is there a way to suppress that? Some sort of universally synchronized setting of all ports?
2. When creating the date, with day_enable coming from the time component as clock enable just like sec_enable comes from the clock divider, I'd have a process that counts up the days and on day 30 (or 31 or ... depending on the month and leap year) does month <= month + 1 and so on. I originally checked for the number of days within the  if day_enable = '1' part, but simulation shows that if my clock starts on Feb 28 during a leap year, it still takes the default value (is_leap ='0') because the result of the check "if (year1 mod 4=0)" is only applied in the next cycle. Vice versa for the 30/31 choice. When checking for that right after "if rising_edge(clk_base) then", it works, but it seems overkill to check for this every X ns if the days (and thus, months) change so rarely. Where has my thinking gone astray?

In my mind, somehow cascading the whole thing would solve questions 1 and 2, but I have no idea if it is actually done this way and if so, how. What is the standard practice for avoiding the issues I just described? I am sure the answer is quite trivial, but please help me out here.

Comment: This is really two questions. You should post them separately.

Comment: Glitches are bad news if your FPGA/IC outputs them. Glitches cause the big transistors in the output cells to switch on and off rapidly, which draws excessive current and causes interference. The output of a flip-flop is _coherent_. That is, it does not glitch. Therefore, you should always drive the outputs of any FPGA/IC directly from a flip-flop rather than via combinational logic.

Comment: In your example, you do seem to be driving the outputs of your FPGA directly from flip-flops. `sec` will synthesise as flip-flops, because _any signal assigned in a clocked process will synthesise as flip-flops_. The line `output_seconds <= sec1;` if executed _unconditionally_ (ie not from inside some other conditional statement) will not add any logic.

Comment: Ok, I hoped some sort of cascading technique would solve both issues, thus one post. Am I understanding you correctly that I should not use a signal but instead drive the ports within the process? But won't that give me a multiple drivers error? And make me unable to use integers for the counter but convert them to std_logic_vector for the output?

Comment: If you meant something else, could you give me a simple example how to drive the ports? By the way, basically all tutorials do it the way I described above, so while I understand why it's bad for the actual FPGA, where can I find a correct implementation?

Comment: My point is that you _are_ driving the outputs directly from flip-flops, so either please describe in more detail what you mean by 'glitches' or are you sure that there is not some other logic between `secs` and the output.

Comment: Renaud is right. That's not a glitch, that's just a difference in propagation delay between the different flip-flops and the outputs. Flip-flops are real electronics with real transistors in. They are connected through the FPGA outputs by real pieces of metal and via real transistors in the output cells. You wouldn't expect the delay through six separate pieces of metal and six separate sets of transistors to be the same. If you drive a 7-segment display from this, there is no way a human could perceive such a short time.

Comment: "but my questions are independent of actual hardware" <-- no, that's not true. Questions like these have different answers if you're writing code for ASIC of FPGA.

Answer (score 1):

1. If your counter is sec1 and it is assigned in a true synchronous process like:

   ```
   process(clk_base)
   begin
     if rising_edge(clk_base) then
       if(set_time='1') 
         if (sec_enable= '1') then
           sec1 <= sec1+1;
           if(sec1 = 59) then
             sec1<=0;
           end if;
         end if;
       end if;
     end if;
   end process;
   ```

then `sec1` is the output of a register and there are no glitches on it. If you assign it to another signal in a concurrent signal assignment (outside any process) of the form:

```
    output_seconds <= sec1;
```

there will be no glitches on `output_seconds`.

2. Hardware exists or not. Transistors are not dynamically added and removed from the chip. So, if you added some hardware to compare something with something else, it will be there, even if it is not used at all. The only drawback of letting a part of your hardware work while it is not needed is, maybe, energy waste.

Note that if you have hardware that is not always useful, it is time to think whether it could be shared among several similar operations...

Comment: 1. My process is just like that, the difference being an asychronous reset. Is that to blame for the glitches in the post synthesis simulation?
2. The "check for month length" if-part is of course always there, so the corresponding hardware is always there, of course, but before the clock enable it will be called much more often than afterwards. Energy waste is not an issue here, but there must be a better way, since I only call it with every clk because its result is delayed by 1 day cycle?!

Comment: Well, if your async reset glitches, then yes, it might be to blame. Can you please explain a bit more what you see exactly? Is it one bit of your output that toggles several times per clock period? Or is it the complete multi-bit value that changes several times per clock period?

Comment: I added a picture above. What confuses me further is that the correct values are 1s apart (despite the delay with regards to the triggering edge), but the glitch comes before that, so without delays it would actually precede the edge. I don't get why such a simple design (standard in most tutorials) would glitch at the output (as you said, it shouldn't). The reset itself doesn't glitch, it works as it should, and the glitches appear regardless of whether reset = '1' or '0'. I can't imagine why the hw would be synthesized in such an unreliable just because the reset is async.

Comment: I see the glitches at the output_seconds even though my code is akin to the first example here: http://www.csit-sun.pub.ro/courses/Masterat/Xilinx%20Synthesis%20Technology/toolbox.xilinx.com/docsan/xilinx4/data/docs/xst/hdlcode6.html

Comment: The duration of your *glitch* is 200 ps. What you see is not really a glitch, it is the difference of the propagation delays between bit 0 and bit 1 of your output. Nothing to worry about, unless you intend to use this output in an unusual way.

Comment: Don't these effects stack (concerning minutes, hours, days etc.), causing these outputs to become unreliable?
As for the "check for month length" if-part, is there a better way than what I described?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *stack* but if your whole design is synchronous, no, the fact that different signals have different propagation delays will not be a problem... as long as your worst propagation delay is less than your clock period.

Comment: You wrote above *before the clock enable it will be called much more often than afterwards*. Hardware is not *called*. If the inputs of a combinatorial part change, the signals propagate and the new output is updated. Whether these inputs come from a register or another combinatorial does not make a difference. If you want to freeze the inputs of a combinatorial part to save energy, use registers that sample new inputs only when needed. Anyway, SO is not the best place to discuss the basics of digital hardware. It is more programming-oriented.

Comment: Wrong choice of words, sorry.

Comment: No problem. May I suggest that you have a look at some topics of the [VHDL documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vhdl/topics)? I suggest [Digital hardware design using VHDL in a nutshell](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vhdl/5525/digital-hardware-design-using-vhdl-in-a-nutshell#t=201707171240002375435) and, maybe, [Getting started with vhdl](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vhdl/3803/getting-started-with-vhdl#t=201707171240526384281).

Comment: How did you simulate? Did you just use the code you wrote or did you put in some kind of technology dependent library? To keep it simple you should not simulate using the gates specific to the FPGA. Just simulate the code as is (not technology specific) and you should not see any propagation delay "glitches" that can confuse you. Only if you have timing problems just you experiment with technology dependent simulation.

Comment: Do you mean the behavioral simulation instead of post-synthesis?

Comment: Weird I had the exact same behavior but in my casethe "glitched" sun was registered and forwarded to the block ram address.. resulting in a write to two addresses earlier than intended

Comment: In my case, the problem went away when I added a rst rule (there are two registers in Cascade, I forgot to rst the second). But worth noting, I only used sync rst. How could that happen? Does having an rst pin have an effect on the synthesizer requiring setup and hold times in one case and not in the other case?